# Is multiple initialization of perl engine (C/C++) forbidden?

Tags: c++, c, perl, perl-module

I'm wondering if multiple initialization of perl engine in the same process is safe. By initialization I mean such combination:

```
PERL_SYS_INIT3(&argc,&argv,&env);
my_perl = perl_alloc();
perl_construct(my_perl);
perl_parse(my_perl, NULL, argc, argv, (char **)NULL);
perl_run(my_perl);
perl_destruct(my_perl);
perl_free(my_perl);
PERL_SYS_TERM();
```

and this is done one after another, without any concurrency.

My problem is that some perl scripts crash perl's engine (inside Perl_op_free) during second run. I modified perl.exe (perlmain.c) just to run engine several times without my rubbish and I got the same result:

```
//perlmain.c
int
main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
    int res;
    res = RunPerl(argc,argv,env);
    res = RunPerl(argc,argv,env);
    return res;
}
```

Is multiple initialization forbidden? Or it should be done another way? I tried perl engines from 5.8 up to 5.18, everyone seems to have the same problem.

Comment: While I don't know the absolute answer, based on [perdoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html#Maintaining-multiple-interpreter-instances), it would appear that this is not possible

Comment: If Perl was compiled with `-DMULTIPLICITY` (implied by `-Dusethreads`), you can not only have multiple interpreters, but multiple interpreters simultaneously. Not sure what you can do without `-DMULTIPLICITY`.

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=850886

Comment: Finaly I found! Of course multiple interpreters are possible, and -DMULTIPLICITY is used by default during perl build. Problem is that PERL_SYS_INIT/PERL_SYS_TERM can be used __only once__ per process, regardless how many interpreters are created. Thank you both for your help!